# using async and inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've added 'async' to some of my scripts (see below) however my back to top link script now doesn't display or function. Any ideas as I don't know JavaScript massively well and I can't seem to find the answers? below is the code that sits at the bottom of body:

```
<div class="sprite topsite active" style="display: none;">
<a href="#nav">Back to top arrow</a>
</div>

<script async src="content/js/hideaddressbar.min.js"></script>
<script async src="content/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="content/js/picturefill.min.js"></script>

<!-- back to top link -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Show or hide the sticky footer button
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('.topsite').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('.topsite').fadeOut(300);
            }
        });

        // Animate the scroll to top
        $('.topsite').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that: "With `async`, browser will continue to load the HTML page and render it while the browser load & execute the script at the same time. With `defer`, however, browser will run your script when the page finished parsing." Also note that in you case you inline script might run before all you `async` scripts.

Comment: You mentioned using `async`, however, I don't see anything that appears to be asyncronous

Comment: Go check your browser console - likely you'll find a message there telling you that $ is not defined. Which should not surprise you - after all, you told the browser that you don't care when it will load the file that contains the jQuery source code. So either reverse your changes - or go properly read up on the implications what you are doing, and how to fix/mitigate them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your inline script is dependant on jQuery. So if you load jQuery asynchronously (the page will continue to load while jQuery loads in the background) you will have to wait with your scripts until jQuery is loaded.

I'd suggest you load jQuery first and synchronously, so that it can be the basis of your other scripts.

The async-attribute is meant to boost loading speed by loading scripts in parallel, that are not necessary at document.ready.